# Creating an Insert Statement for mysql table

Tags: coldfusion

I am creating a INSERT Starement for my table. Till now all going good and i have been able to create the Insert Statement. Only Issue Left is: It shows a trailing comma after the end of every single record. Can you guys have a look around what mess I am doing here

```
<cfset listcount = getQueryColumns(insertData)>
    <cfset counter = 1>
      <cfloop query="insertData">
      <cfoutput>
        INSERT INTO `mytable` (#listcount#) 
        VALUES(
            <cfloop index="col" list="#listcount#">'#insertData[col][currentRow]#' 
                <cfif counter LT insertData.recordcount>,</cfif> 
            </cfloop>);<br><br>
      </cfoutput>  
      <cfset counter++>
      </cfloop>
```

Comment: What is the source of `insertData`? If that data comes from another table in the same database, you can use an INSERT/SELECT statement instead of looping. FYI, if you really do need a loop you should use `cfqueryparam`. It utilizes bind variables which improve performance by reusing execution plans when the same statement is executed multiple times, as with looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it. I believe this is what you need:

```
<cfset listcount = getQueryColumns(insertData)>
  <cfloop query="insertData">
  <cfset counter = 1>
  <cfoutput>
    INSERT INTO `mytable` (#listcount#) 
    VALUES(
        <cfloop index="col" list="#listcount#">'#insertData[col][currentRow]#' 
            <cfif counter LT listcount>,</cfif> 
            <cfset counter++>
        </cfloop>);<br><br>
  </cfoutput>  
  </cfloop>
```

What I changed is:

- As Dan Bracuk pointed out, I moved `<cfset counter++>` inside the inner loop. I also moved `<cfset counter = 1>` inside the outer loop, as it will need to be reinitialized through successive `INSERT` statements.
- I changed `<cfif counter LT insertData.recordcount>` to `<cfif counter LT listcount>`, as you don't want to iterate over the recordcount (this is why your commas stopped appearing after Priority, which was the 8th field). Instead, you want to iterate over the number of columns.

Comment: Thanks Pal, we are very near to our Goal. Now the code works almost good, respectively at the end of the insert statement, it gives an extra comma. Here is the example: **INSERT INTO `mytable` (`ID`,`by`,`subject`,`body`,`uploads`,`created`,`modified`,`priority`,`status`,`parent`,`DEPARTMENT_ID`,`internalnote`,`threadID`,`holdby`,`lockedby`,`rejectedby`) VALUES( '17' , '1' , 'This is a New Ticket' , 'Completed Details of the Ticket adn now run on the shoes' , '0' , '2014-03-06 13:18:02.0' , '2014-03-12 16:20:04.0' , 'Normal' , 'Resolved' , '0' , '5' , '' , '17' , '' , '' , '' , );**

Comment: Well, you're the one with access to the data, so you're going to have to debug that to figure out what's going on. A starting point, of course, would be to see if your `getQueryColumns(insertData)` is really returning the number of columns that you think it should.

Please remember to mark one of the answers as correct (this one, I hope -- but whichever one helped you the most).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to the fact that you are incrementing your counter in the outer loop instead of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: See my more recent answer. I'm leaving this one in place because the comments were useful in the diagnosis.**

I think Dan Bracuk is correct about your counter increment. But you might be able to simplify your code and avoid the `<cfif >` statement entirely if you you use the `list` attribute in `<cfqueryparam >`. For example:

```
<cfqueryparam value="#NAME_OF_LIST#" list="yes" >
```

By default this will put a comma between your list values before sending them to the database.

Check out the other attributes it takes at http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf8/#cfqueryparam.

Comment: He can't use cfqueryparam because at this point, he doesn't have a query.  He is simply outputting a string.

Comment: Fair enough -- but what about converting his source data to a list using `ValueList()`? I think this would let him avoid both `<cfloop >` operations.

Comment: Hi Guys, Dan is right, I need not use the cfqueryparam here, i just need a statement like insert. I had moved the counter inside the second loop. My Total recordcount is 8. The Statement being is displayed as like this, after some fields, the comma is not showing. I think something is wrong with the <cfif statement>..

Comment: Example: `INSERT INTO mytable (ID,by,subject,body,uploads,created,modified,priority,status,parent,DEPARTMENT_ID,internalnote,threadID) VALUES( '17' , '1' , 'This is a New Ticket' , 'Completed Details of the Ticket adn now run on the shoes' , '0' , '2014-03-06 13:18:02.0' , '2014-03-12 16:20:04.0' , 'Normal' 'Resolved' '0' '5' '' '17' );` See after the Priority, The cooma Field is not showing